# What are built-in types(or non-defined types) in GoLang?

Tags: go

Spec says:

> A value x is assignable to a variable of type T ("x is assignable to T") if one of the following conditions applies:

> x's type V and T have identical underlying types and at least one of V or T is not a defined type.

---

numerical type `uint8` is a [defined type](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_definitions), so with the above rule, assignability fails in the below code:

```
package main

type Point struct {
    x uint8
    y uint8
}

type Polar Point

var p Polar = Point{x: 1, y: 2}

func main() {

}
```

---

What are non-defined types in GoLang, to test the above rule?

Comment: Types without an identifier bound to them. Say `123`, the type of the constant 123 is undefined, that's why you can assign it to an `int` variable, to `uint64` variable, to a `float32` variable...

Comment: @mkopriva `var p struct { x int   y int } = Point{x: 1, y: 2}`  you mean unnamed types? here type of variable `p` is unnamed

Answer (score 4):

A non-defined type is a type without an identifier assigned to them. For instance:

```
type S struct {
  A int
}

func main() {
  var s S
  // You can assign a literal struct with the same underlying type to a variable of type S
  s=struct{A int}{1}
}
```

Above, the type of `struct {A int}` is not a defined type.

Comment: `struct {A int}` is a type literal and type of variable `s` is unnamed type

Comment: Type of `s` is `S`. `struct {A int}` is a type.

Comment: Sorry... `struct{A int}{1}` is a type literal

Comment: @overexchange No. `struct{A int}` is the type literal, `struct{A int}{1}` is a compositle literal, creating a value of the (anonymous) type `struct{A int}`.

Answer (score 0):

```
// The underlying types of the following ones are both int.
type (
    MyInt int
    Age   MyInt
)

// The following new types have different underlying types.
type (
    IntSlice   []int   // underlying type is []int
    MyIntSlice []MyInt // underlying type is []MyInt
    AgeSlice   []Age   // underlying type is []Age
)

// The underlying types of []Age, Ages, and AgeSlice
// are all the non-defined type []Age.
type Ages AgeSlice
```

[Type System Overview](https://go101.org/article/type-system-overview.html)

Comment: there is no such things lke `non defined` types. It would be a compile error. Especially in the paradigm of a statically typed programming langage. They are unnamed, if you like, or probably, more appropriately, a type litteral made of the composite type (slice) and the named type Age. https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_identity - https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_definitions